# Data initialize is called before Report Start in Active Reports (Data dynamics)

Tags: report, activereports, componentone

Per Active reports documentation, the Report start is called first and Data initialize. Any reference to Data source inside Report start will invoke Data Initialize event.  I am modifying an existing report; and to my surprise the order is reversed. I have an existing logic to get the count of nodes (my datasource is xml) in data initialize event; just because the event firing sequence is reversed, I am getting 0 as count always.

I am using Active reports for .NET 2.0 ( I think the version is 4.***). As I dont have support for the designer, I have the designer xml and code behind.

Please suggest what could force the event sequence to correct order.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably not enough information for us to help you here. We'd need to see the report code at least, but better if you can do some debugging to find out more detail about what specific code you have that is causing the trouble.

I'm actually not sure about event order in this specific case, but to troubleshoot you could try with a new blank report to verify the event order in that case and move over one piece of code at a time to find out which line of code causes the event order to change.

Comment: I can't try a sample new report as I dont have VS2003/2005 with which the Active reports work. All I have is the designer files in XML. I tried the debugger; its not going into Data initialize; but in the watch seeing the value is being set.

Comment: YOur best bet would be to get a copy of VS to troubleshoot with. However, you can still take approach I suggested using the designer to create a new/clean report and add one line of script to it until you see the same problem.